# insert into an array if value is not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array built like this:

```
test[0].age = "15-24"; test[0].value= "5";

test[1].age = "45-54"; test[1].value= "10";
```

etc

I have another array built like this:

```
ageRange[0] = "1-14";

ageRange[1] = "15-24";
```

etc

The ageRange has all age ranges - and the test array only has some of them.

I want to rebuild the test array to include all ages of the ageRange array and if they aren't already in the array, assign them a value of 0. What is the best way of doing this? Also - they need to be sequentially added.

Comment: Thus if there are multiple times age `15-24` the values should be summed ? What if `test` contains an age range that is not in the `ageRange` array ?

Comment: can you post your complete code?

Comment: @Weedoze - in this instance - there is only unique indexes for the ages so there's no need to sum

Comment: @John What about the second question ? `45-54` is not present in `ageRange`

Comment: @Weedoze yes it is - as i said in my question all age ranges are included

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi I feel like my complete code would complicate the question which I think is pretty straight forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var AgeArray=["15-24","25-30","30-35","40-45","45-50","55-60"];

var NewArray=[{ age: "15-24", value: "5" }, { age: "25-30", value: "10" }, { age: "45-50", value: "15" }, { age: "55-60", value: "20" }];

$.each(AgeArray,function(i,val){


 var filtered = $(NewArray).filter(function(){
        return this.age == val;
    });
    if(filtered.length == 0)
{
var newobj={};newobj.age=val;newobj.value=0;NewArray.push(newobj)}

});

$('#result').text(JSON.stringify(NewArray));
```

**Output**

https://jsfiddle.net/wy18u0zu/2/

**JSON.stringify(NewArray)**

"[{"age":"15-24","value":"5"},{"age":"25-30","value":"10"},{"age":"45-50","value":"15"},{"age":"55-60","value":"20"},{"age":"30-35","value":0},{"age":"40-45","value":0}]"

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate the array with the new ranges and iterate the `test` array while checking the left part. If the left part is not equal, then insert a new object to the test array at the actual position.

```js
var test = [{ age: "15-24", value: "5" }, { age: "45-54", value: "10" }],
    ageRange = ["1-14", "15-24"],
    i = 0;

ageRange.forEach(function (a) {
    function getLeft(s) { return +s.split('-')[0]; }

    var left = getLeft(a);
    while (getLeft(test[i].age) < left) {
        i++;
    }
    getLeft(test[i].age) === left || test.splice(i, 0, { age: a, value: '0' });
});

console.log(test);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ageRange.forEach((age, i) => {
let agePresent = test.filter((obj) => obj.age === age).length;
if (!agePresent) {
var objt = ({val : 0, age : age});
test.splice(i,0,objt);
}
});
```

I ended up getting some help and came up with this solution, which was easier for me to wrap my head around although more or less the same as user1960808's solution. I appreciate the help @user1960808 and @Nina Scholz both of your solutions also worked great and were interesting ways to tackle the problem.

edit:mods feel free to mark any of these as the answer as they are all valid